# How to Override Parent Theme Dynamically Using SCSS

Tags: css, angular, sass

The list of support chats in our back office support app can get quite long, so I'm trying to apply the theme of the client's product to their chat in the list so that it has that product's colour. Since all of the theme class styles are generated with the same SCSS mixins, they all have the same specificity, so if a support user has changed their theme to a class that happens to fall after that of a given conversation, it incorrectly overrides the chat theme.

## styles.scss

```css
.theme {
  &--pink {
    $primary: mat-palette($vt-primary);
    $accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
    $theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent);

    @include angular-material-theme($theme);
  }

  &--red {
    $primary: mat-palette($vt-primary);
    $accent: mat-palette($mat-red, A200, A100, A400);
    $theme: mat-dark-theme($primary, $accent);
    background: #303030;
    color: white;

    @include angular-material-theme($theme);
  }

  &--orange {
    $primary: mat-palette($vt-primary);
    $accent: mat-palette($mat-orange, A200, A100, A400);
    $theme: mat-dark-theme($primary, $accent);
    background: #303030;
    color: white;

    @include angular-material-theme($theme);
  }

  &--green {
    $primary: mat-palette($vt-primary);
    $accent: mat-palette($mat-green, A200, A100, A400);
    $theme: mat-dark-theme($primary, $accent);
    background: #303030;
    color: white;

    @include angular-material-theme($theme);
  }
```

## component HTML

```html
<div class="red">
  <ul class="chat-list">
    <li class="theme--pink">
      <mat-icon color="accent">circle</mat-icon>
      Example Chat
    </li>
    <li class="theme--red">
      <mat-icon color="accent">circle</mat-icon>
      Example Chat
    </li>
    <li class="theme--orange">
      <mat-icon color="accent">circle</mat-icon>
      Example Chat
    </li>
    <li class="theme--green">
      <mat-icon color="accent">circle</mat-icon>
      Example Chat
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here the chat that should be pink inherits the red theme from the parent. I can't just change the order or add `!important` because in another case the chat may be pink and the root red.

Here is a [stackblitz showing my problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-theme-overrides-nxnnjk?file=src/app/app.component.html). I want the chat icons to keep their colour even when the root theme is changed.

I started to follow [this tutorial on dynamic theming in angular](https://betterprogramming.pub/angular-remote-themes-21ff698ed12e), thinking I could use TypeScript to change the order of the cascade dynamically, but that relies on disabling scss extraction which, as far as I can tell, is not possible in the most recent Angular releases.

Comment: Please post code here. It is not sufficient to add a link. Explain the code and your issue. No one is going to read through all of that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've added some elements to make my problem clearer, but couldn't that have been phrased more empathetically? This is exactly why I was hesitant to post here in the first place.

Comment: (◔_◔)  . It says Please. It is factual. It explains the issue. Should I get you a lemon tea and weighted blanket as well?

Comment: "Could you post a code example in the question? Having just a link isn't sufficient as most people on here don't have the patience to read that much text in one go." Conveys the exact same message. Doesn't need a please because it isn't unnecessarily snarky. This is why SO makes beginners give up.  A lemon tea would be lovely thanks.

Comment: There is nothing snarky about my first comment. It is terse. But if you'd read the "how to ask" and empathetically pretended you're talking to a busy colleague....